# reCaptcha callback: function not being enabled to remove disable attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recaptcha

Guys I am trying to remove the disable attribute from a button through recaptcha call back when it is true through a script but it is not working. Can anyone help? Code is the below.

```js
function recaptchaCallback(){
 $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

```html
<form>    
<fieldset>
        <!-- reCaptcha -->
 
      
    <div class="form-group text-center">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
     <div class="g-recaptcha col-md-4"   data-sitekey="6Lf3JDAUAAAAAJ3Y4oPhVeuAx0K98sCCYju7HcT1" ></div    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" data-recaptcha="true" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  

    <!-- Button -->
     <div class="form-group text-center">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4"><br>
        <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" disabled>SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    

    
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your code is fine, definitely your recaptcha call back is not being called. You can verify that using a console.log. can you post the JavaScript that has the code where recaptcha callback function is called

Comment: @shakeel I dont have any more client side code. All I have is server side validation which is working fine. Code is below:$googleURL= 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $googleRecaptchaPK = "6Lf3JDAUAAAAANsQx9mPnMosKmvE_i4ug7MrBC0v";        
        $response=file_get_contents($googleURL."?secret=".$googleRecaptchaPK."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remote".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $googleData= json_decode($response);

Comment: SOLVED: data-callback="recaptchaCallback" had to be included in the recaptcha div

Comment: That is correct. And I was saying that too, somehow the callback code was not getting executed. And like you said Google has it documented here:

data-callback: callback Optional. The name of your callback function, executed when the user submits a successful response. The g-recaptcha-response token is passed to your callback.